# Unexpected token ! within if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is my markup

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJ1xT.png

I tried `$('.post-form').find('p:first').text().indexOf("Logged") !='')`, and try to detect whether Logged is set or not, but I got this error `Unexpected token !`

Comment: can you post the entire if statement please

Comment: indexOf return numaric value and you are comparing it with string

Comment: All these comments / answers about `indexOf` returning an integer are great but they don't address the actual problem ~ *"Unexpected token !"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get error `Unexpected token !` because your statement

```
$('.post-form').find('p:first').text().indexOf("Logged") !='')
```

is not complete.

Use `if` condition  and `indexOf` as shown below :-

```
if( $('.post-form').find('p:first').text().indexOf("Logged") > -1)
```

The `indexOf()` method returns the position of the first occurrence of a specified value in a string.

This method returns `-1` if the value to search never occurs

Comment: @downvoter care to comment..

Comment: **-1**  for not targeting the `Unexpected token !` error. Most likely adding the `if` solves it but it should be mentioned as this is the actual problem the question is about. The wrong comparison is an other error.

Comment: @t.niese..i have added appropriate explanation..i have write that use if condition as shown..

Comment: but, what if this answer covers both problems, then why -ve?

Comment: @muneebShabbir...sorry..but i didn't get you..

Comment: i am saying your answer cover both problems, Issue of `if` and issue of `comparison`. i think this should not be in negative

Comment: You wrote the explanation why the if condition wouldn't be called when the `Unexpected token !` error is solved, but you didn't explain that what the `Unexpected token !` is. If the OP would know what the error `Unexpected token !` is about the OP would have been able to solve it.

Comment: @muneebShabbir...yes this is what i m saying...i don't know why people downvote without any reason...

Comment: pls upvote this reply, this helped!

Comment: @t.niese...Unexpected token ! ..is due to that OP hasen't use if properly

Comment: @t.niese your point of view is right but you can add a constructive comment and post your answer, rather than downvote. downvote is helpfull when someone answers a total blunder. i upvote it to make it even

Comment: @muneebShabbir...yes absolutely...thanks

Comment: @muneebShabbir and @Exception I removed the down vote at the time the answer was complete. I explained the down-vote with the comment (which was not immediately there, but that was because of a connection problem). Maybe I should think over immediate down voting, but in the past I saw that those comments where often not take into account and later down votes with comments had no effect. **A note:** While the answer is now complete I would always add the links to MDN with functions like `indexOf`, as this would maybe help the OP to find help himself in future.

Comment: @t.niese..yes providing links is helpful..but i included a sufficient explanation that how to use .indexof() in answer only so i skip that...

Comment: @Exception The explanation is for sure sufficient. That kind of error might because of the lack of a good reference site. So linking against MDN (while still having that explanation in the answer) to show a source where all those functions are explained might help with future problems.

Answer (score 0):

`indexOf` returns integer not string.

It returns the position where the specified searchvalue occurs for the first time, or -1 if it never occurs.

You get error `Unexpected token !` because your statement

```
$('.post-form').find('p:first').text().indexOf("Logged") !='')
```

is incomplete.

Following should work:

```
if($('.post-form').find('p:first').text().indexOf("Logged") >= 0){
    ...
}
```

[**See DEMO here**](http://jsfiddle.net/hiral/612g6kjm/).